# Undefined method :name when showing listing (ruby on rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a user profile page that shows all the listings the user made. Each listing has a 'show' link that links to a new page that shows the listing individually on a different page. I got this to work for the user profile page.
I'm using this link

```
<li><%= link_to "Show", user_listing_path(name: @user.name, id: listing.id) %></li>
```

However, now I want to create a listings index page that shows all listings of every user. Each listing again should have a 'show' link that links to a page that shows the listing individually. The same link that worked on the user profile page does not work on the listing index page.

I get the following error undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
and it points to

<%= link_to "Show", user_listing_path(name: @user.name, id: listing.id) %>

Does anyone know why?

User show file (show.html.erb)

```
<div class= "showuser">
                <div class="error-message">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
      </div>



<h4>
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
<%= @user.name %>
</h4>


        <div class="span 8">
            <% if @user.listings.any? %>
            <h3> Job Posts (<%= @user.listings.count %>)</h3>
            <ol class="listings">
                <%= render @listings %>
                <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
        <% end %>
            </ol>
            <%= will_paginate @listings %>
            <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

listing file (_listing.html.erb)

```
<li>
    <h4><%= listing.title %></h4>
    <p><%= listing.location %></h4><br>
    <span class="content"><%= listing.description %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(listing.created_at) %> ago
    </span>
    <li><%= link_to "Show", user_listing_path(name: @user.name, id: listing.id) %></li>
    <% if current_user?(listing.user) %>
    <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_listing_path %></li>
     <%= link_to "delete", listing, method: :delete,
                                    data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                    title: listing.description %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

listing controller

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy, :edit, :update]
    before_action :correct_user,   only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]

    def create
        @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)
        if @listing.save
            flash[:success] = "Job Post created"
            redirect_to current_user
            else
                render 'listings/new'
            end
        end



        def edit
        end

    def update
        if @listing.update_attributes(listing_params)
        flash[:success] = "Listing updated"
        redirect_to @listing
    else 
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

        def show
            @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
            @listing = Listing.find_by_id(params[:id])

        end

        def new
            @listing = Listing.new
            @listings = Listing.paginate(page: params[:page])
        end

    def destroy 
        @listing.destroy
        redirect_to current_user
    end

    def index
    @listings = Listing.all
    @listings = Listing.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    @listing = Listing.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end



    private 



    def listing_params
        params.require(:listing).permit(:description, :location, :title)
    end

    def correct_user
        @listing = current_user.listings.find_by(id: params[:id])
        redirect_to current_user if @listing.nil?
    end

end
```

listing show file (show.html.erb) Shows listing indivudally

```
<div class="show_listing">

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3><%= @listing.title %></h3>
        <h3><%= @listing.location %></h3>
        <p><%= @listing.description %></p><br>
        <div class="center">
        <%= link_to "Apply Now", '#', class: "btn btn-info", data: {no_turbolink: true} %>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="show_link_position">
<% if current_user == @listing.user %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path, class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', current_user, class: "btn btn-link" %>
</div>
```

listing index file (index.html.erb)

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="categories-container">
     <div class="boxed grid-3 category-link ">
    <li><%= link_to "Find Jobs",  findjobs_path, class: "category-link"%></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Post Jobs",  new_path, class: "category-link" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Find Jobs",  findjobs_path, class: "category-link" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Post Jobs",  new_path, class: "category-link" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Find Jobs",  findjobs_path, class: "category-link" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Post Jobs",  new_path, class: "category-link" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Find Jobs",  findjobs_path, class: "category-link" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Post Jobs",  new_path, class: "category-link" %></li>
        </div>
    </div>



<div class="table-container">
<div class= "grid-8 grid-moved">
  <% @listings.each do |listing| %>

  <h4><%= listing.title %></h4>
  <h5> <%= listing.user.name %>, Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(listing.created_at) %> ago</h5>
    <h5>Job Description:</h5>
      <p><%= listing.description %></p>
    <p>Location: <%= listing.location %></p>
    <li><%= link_to "Show", user_listing_path(name: @user.name, id: listing.id) %></li>
    <br><hr><br>

  <% end %>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="pagination">
    <%= will_paginate @listings %>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes

Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :listings

root 'static_pages#home'

```
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',   to: 'sessions#new',          via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via:'delete'
  match '/help',      to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/contact',   to: 'static_pages#contact',  via: 'get'
  match '/about',     to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get' 
  match '/new',     to: 'listings#new',   via: 'get' 
  match '/users/:name/:id', to: 'listings#show', via: :get, as: :user_listing
  match '/findjobs',     to: 'listings#index',   via: 'get'
```

Let me know if I forgo any important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined `@user` in the controller.

In the next line, you appropriately access the listing user, as follows:
`<% if current_user?(listing.user) %>`

You simply need to adjust your code to look like:

`<li><%= link_to "Show", user_listing_path(name: listing.user.name, id: listing.id) %></li>`

Make sense?

Comment: This works. Could you explain to me why this link works on the index page and the other one on the user profile page? I'm new to rails and really would like to learn and understand what I'm writing.

Comment: You only set the `@user` variable in the `show` and `index` actions in your controller. These variable assignments do not persist beyond the request in which they were assigned. If you render the same partial in one action where you have defined `@user`, and one where you have not, it will work for one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<li><%= link_to "Show", user_listing_path(@user, listing) %></li>
```

And on your controller:

```
def show 
  @user = User.find(params[:id)
  @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"listings", :id=>"308", :name=>nil} missing required keys: [:name]